# Problem booting after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, uefi, boot-repair, 23.04

Ubuntu proposed me to upgrade to 23.04 from Ubuntu 22.04. I accepted. The problem is that when the CPU restarted it got stuck, Ubuntu wasn't starting.
I made a live USB with Ubuntu 23.04, installed Boot-repair, but Boot-Repair told me *"The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit ([www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd](http://www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd)), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature."*

I made a new live USB using the GPT partition scheme instead of MBR, I went to the CPU BIOS to deactivate the BIOS/CSM/legacy mode to force him using EFI. Unfortunately the CPU doesn't want to launch Ubuntu from my live USB.
Here is the [Boot Info Summary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sXSXr62CVg/).

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt3)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 23.04
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 23.04 on sda3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GF114M [GeForce GTX 670M] 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 23.04, lunar, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 4.6.5(4.6) from American Megatrends Inc.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).


0a832cd2c33c8a146b78778df8d33417   sda2/BOOT/fbx64.efi
abfc1dc97795531c0390328f9dd1a281   sda2/BOOT/mmx64.efi
7e494801bb7163fd063f386d7bc75ed8   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
abfc1dc97795531c0390328f9dd1a281   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    128 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdc2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdc2    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 119.24 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk identifier: D2D99D60-1C94-472E-B3B0-C492B3BB41C1
        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   1054719   1050624   513M EFI System
sda3  1054720 250068991 249014272 118.7G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x4cccbd3c
      Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1        2048 976769023 976766976 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk sdc: 14.84 GiB, 15938355200 bytes, 31129600 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0e2a5668
      Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdc1  *         128 31129487 31129360 14.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
sdc2       31129488 31129550       63 31.5K ea Linux extended boot

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:128GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA M4-CT128M4SSD2:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:540MB:538MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
3:540MB:128GB:127GB:ext4::;
sdb:500GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST9500420ASG:;
1:1049kB:500GB:500GB:ntfs::;
sdc:15.9GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:65.5kB:15.9GB:15.9GB:fat32::boot, lba;
2:15.9GB:15.9GB:32.3kB:::bls_boot;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1                                               d2f4fae9-1732-406d-b630-e1306bbda7de             
├─sda2 vfat     4923-9CD3                            61b40228-4f01-486c-98d8-1715a67f3b36             EFI System Partition
└─sda3 ext4     09cbb845-707c-496c-be87-4011d04eb235 50f94af3-e0ab-4896-bd3a-94ba7214340d             
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 ntfs     BC0AE0F90AE0B196                     4cccbd3c-01                          Data        
sdc                                                                                                   
├─sdc1 vfat     F4B8-1908                            0e2a5668-01                          UBUNTU 23_0 
└─sdc2                                               0e2a5668-02                                      

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                 505.9M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                  76.7G  29% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdb1                 132.3G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdc1                  10.2G  31% /cdrom
overlay                        0 100% /tmp/tmpfuzljpds/root.dir

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 09cbb845-707c-496c-be87-4011d04eb235 root hd0,gpt3 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda3/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   09cbb845-707c-496c-be87-4011d04eb235
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-33-generic   09cbb845-707c-496c-be87-4011d04eb235
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-32-generic   09cbb845-707c-496c-be87-4011d04eb235
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda3/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=09cbb845-707c-496c-be87-4011d04eb235 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=4923-9CD3  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda3/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  23.685947418 = 25.432592384   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 106.792854309 = 114.667954176  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  24.343936920 = 26.139103232   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  35.851749420 = 38.495522816   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic                  2
  24.343936920 = 26.139103232   boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-33-generic                  2
  35.851749420 = 38.495522816   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
  41.480754852 = 44.539621376   boot/initrd.img                                1
  41.699428558 = 44.774420480   boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic               1
  41.480754852 = 44.539621376   boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-33-generic               1
  41.699428558 = 44.774420480   boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda3: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43263 Dec  9  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Feb 26  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Sep  2  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

====================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda3,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

 The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature.

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 23.04 entry (sda2/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.
```

To get a clearer view of my CPU, this is what GParted shows while on Live USB:

[image: GParted screenshot]

I would like to understand why I can't boot UEFI with my live USB with GPT partition even after having changed the settings in the BIOS.
Ultimately I would like to fix the problem of boot after the upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04.

Rufus config to make the bootable USB;

[image: Rufus config to make the Bootable USB]

Comment: If you *clone* an ISO to thumb-drive, it'll boot in all of BIOS/CSM/legacy, or uEFI/Secure-uEFI modes.  Your details of layout imply you're reformatting the ISO so it'll only boot in specific modes (a *clone* won't ask partitioning details as it overwrites the whole thumb-drive). Why not write the ISO as documented which works in all modes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand you. 
When I boot from USB with MBR partition scheme (working in all modes), the CPU start in BIOS mode, but then boot-repair can't repair my boot and request me to disable the legacy mode. If I do so, the USB with MBR partition scheme doesn't launch Ubuntu, that why I tried making a USB with GPT 
But when I boot from USB with GPT partition scheme it doesn't launch Ubuntu at all, so I can't run Boot-repair to get my booting issue solved.

Comment: If the Ubuntu ISO is written as per Ubuntu documentation, it'll boot & work in all of legacy hardware, more modern uEFI hardware, plus also with Secure-Boot enabled (ie. Secure-uEFI). No layout options (partition schemes) exist when ISO is cloned to drive (*format comes from ISO itself*), so you're not using Ubuntu documented procedures thus modifying the ISO.  Your *modified* ISO is influencing the software thus your issue.

Comment: I made another bootable USB using Rufus as recommended here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview.
Attached screenshot of Rufus showing the options selected. I also selected write DD image when proposed.
I booted from the USB key, installed boot-repair, but again boot-repair refused to do the recommended repair displaying the same message: *"The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware..."*
Is there any other Ubuntu documented procedure I should follow to make this bootable USB?

Answer (score -1):

(I am not allowed to comment so i'll try to provide some suggestions from here)

**beefore using the usb thumb**

1-when you boot into ubuntu does grub boatloader menu appear? If not when try pressing F4 when the company logo's appears from there you can choose:

- Ubuntu os entry
- boot into recovery mode which is a commandline interface
- change firmware setting, from there you can disable secure boot and disable legacy mode, and also change the boot sequence.

**If none of the above seems to work:**

1- Wether its BIOS or EFI you will able to boot to the live usb if you choose it from the boot firmware (when booting press continuously F12)

2- choose to boot from UEFI mode, secure mode OFF

this shall help you to boot into your OS or live usb.